# return to the same script event by click "back" button in the browser

Tags: javascript

I have HTML form (buttons, inputs, etc).
Each component as its own event that trigger specific script.
I want the browser to remember which action happened when the user press the "back" button.
(Example: If the user presses the 'blue button', then he can return to the same place when he clicks "back" in the browser).

I thought of doing this by using local storage in every event that triggered.
Then at the beginning of the code to check which local storage is exist and trigger the event again.

But it seems ineffective to me.
Anyone have a better idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) function to add a "state" to the history. This state could contain the data about the pressed button. In combination with the [PopStateEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PopStateEvent) you can get the previous state that is stored in the history.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier, wouldn't you post this as an answer? I think it's a reusable answer that can serve people in future.